# How to make duplicate button only work on specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a notes app, which displays notes with an edit and delete option.
How do I make the edit/delete button work on only that note div?
Right now, whenever I press edit/delete it only works on the first note and not the specific note which I clicked the button on.

Display.js :

```
 render(){
    const notesList = this.props.notesList;
    const displayNotes = notesList.map( (note) =>
      <div className="display">
        <p id="note">{note}</p>
        <button type="button" class="edit-button" onClick={this.props.edit}>Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="delete-button" onClick={this.props.delete}>Delete</button>
      </div> );

    return <div>{displayNotes}</div>;
  }
```

App.js:

```
handleEdit = () => {
   document.getElementById('note').contentEditable = "true";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dynamic ID, for example ID = "note:' + ID.
Then, manipulate the element using that particular ID by passing an ID to the function argument.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work. In you handleEdit function it just takes the first element with the id 'note'. React doesn't know which note you want to delete or edit. Where are the notes stored? Is the the notesList array the same everywhere in your application? Then you could use for instance the index to filter out the note you want to delete or edit.

In your map function you can add index like this `noteList.map((note, index) => {}`

And maybe your handleEdit function would be something like this:

`const handleEdit = (index) => {theNotes[index].contentEditable = "true"}`

I used a dummy variable theNotes because I don't know how you implemented the state of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some marker that uniquely identifies a given note, such as `id`. Then you pass that `id` to the `edit`/`delete` functions:

```
onClick={() => this.props.edit(note.id)} contentEditable={note.contentEditable}

// ...

this.handleEdit = (id) => {
   const idx = notesList.findIndex(note => note.id === id);
   notesList[idx] = {...notesList[idx], contentEditable: true};
   this.setState({notesList: [...notesList]});
};
```